# .net mvc 404 Custom Error page only work sometimes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, error-handling, custom-error-pages

I'm trying to make an 404 Action on my MVC 4 site to answer a default Image wherever the site gets a 404 on any image.

Everything WORKS FINE when i run locally, but when i publish my website on my server, it doesn't work...

I have on my Web.Config:

```
<customErrors mode="On">
   <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Home/Error404" />
</customErrors>
```

And on my HomeController:

```
    public ActionResult Error404()
    {
        if (Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Contains(".jpg") || Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Contains(".gif") || Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Contains(".png"))
        {
            var dir = Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images/");
            var path = Path.Combine(dir, "imageNotFound400.jpg");
            return base.File(path, "image/jpeg");
        }
        return View();
    }
```

As i said, running locally, it Works, and it returns my default image,
But online, as you can see here:  http://www.ipgii.org.br/Mensagem?pageSize=9&page=30
and here: http://www.ipgii.org.br/Content/Uploads/Thumbnails/alegrai-vos-no-senhor.jpg
it goes to an ugly HTTP 404 error page.

I need help! =]

Comment: Hi, working on this(http://www.ipgii.org.br/MensagemXX) page. Application_Error status with the catch.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a blog post about correctly setting up error pages in an ASP.Net MVC application which is here.

http://web.archive.org/web/20130911212149/http://blog.aquabirdconsulting.com/2012/04/19/setting-up-asp-net-mvc-error-pages/

but what it looks like you are missing is this:

```
<httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
```

This ensures that IIS7+ will not mess with your error pages. Give the post a read and see if you did everything you needed to.

---

### Edit (per OP comment)

You put the httpErrors tag under system.webServer tag. It should look something like this. I added another attribute below that might help for what you are looking to do.

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" errorMode="Custom" />
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Nope... =/ Didn't worked.. Or where exactly do i put the <httpError ... ??

Answer (score 0):

If your application has no problem working locally but is encountering problems when hosted remotely, in my experience most of the time IIS is not configured properly.

In your case, I feel that the account under which the website is running (AppPool Account) may not have the read permission to /Uploads/Thumbnails folder.

Secondly, please check that MapRoute in your Global.aspx.cs file has an escape statement for *.jpg files. Perhaps the IIS is looking for a handler to pass on the request to the uri: http://www.ipgii.org.br/Content/Uploads/Thumbnails/alegrai-vos-no-senhor.jpg and is not able to find it.

Here's the reason for Error Code: 0x80070002 in IIS: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942052

Comment: Add the following code to your global.asax.cs file's RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) method: 
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*favicon}", new { favicon = @"(.*/)?favicon.ico(/.*)?" });
routes.IgnoreRoute("favicon.ico");
routes.IgnoreRoute("*.gif | .png | .jpg | .pdf");